# MultiValueDictKeyError on a Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I cant find the error in here when clicking the follow or unfollow button this message keeps coming.

MultiValueDictKeyError at /unfollow

'userfollow'

Request Method: POST 
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError 
Exception Value:'userfollow'

I tried request.POST.get() and got another error.

views.py

```
def follow(request):
    userfollow = request.POST['userfollow']
    currentUser = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    userfollowData = User.objects.get(username=userfollow)
    f = Follow(user=currentUser, user_follower=userfollowData)
    f.save()
    user_id = userfollowData.id 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(profile, kwargs={'user_id': user_id}))

def unfollow(request):
    userfollow = request.POST['userfollow']
    currentUser = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    userfollowData = User.objects.get(username=userfollow)
    f = Follow.objects.get(user=currentUser, user_follower=userfollowData)
    f.delete()
    user_id = userfollowData.id 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(profile, kwargs={'user_id': user_id}))


profile.html

{% extends "network/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ profile.username }}</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h3 class="col-4">Followers: {{ followers.count}} </h3>
            <h3 class="col-4">Following: {{ following.count}} </h3>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                {% if user != user_profile %}
                    {% if isFollowing %}
                        <form action="{% url 'unfollow' %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" name"userfollow" value="{{ user_profile }}" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Unfollow" />
                        </form>
                    {% else %}
                        <form action="{% url 'follow' %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" name"userfollow" value="{{ user_profile }}" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Follow" />
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in

```
<input type="hidden" name"userfollow" value="{{ user_profile }}" />
```

Change `name"userfollow"` to `name="userfollow"`, this is not sending the parameter properly to the backend